# Read xml OpenCV file using Matlab - Unable to build using mex

Tags: c++, xml, matlab, opencv

Objective: Load .xml OpenCV file using Matlab

Steps and system info:

- Windows 10 x64
- OpenCV 4.5.5 is installed at C:\opencv\
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

[FileStorage.cpp File Reference](http://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/cpp/_file_storage_8cpp.html) - Read OpenCV XML using Matlab
Copied all files and dependencies. The files ([download link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2f4f949ba579afc48259709422b2215820220817145653/a28088)) are stored in Matlab current path.

- FileStorage.cpp
- mex.h
- mexopencv.hpp
- MxArray.hpp

I followed [this instructions (Multiple include paths in mex)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/279800-multiple-include-paths-in-mex) to build using mex:

```
mex -setup C++
path1 = ['-I' fullfile(pwd,'C:\opencv\build\include')];
path2 = ['-I' fullfile(pwd,'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib')];
mex('-v',path1,path2,'FileStorage.cpp');
```

I also tried this:

```
mex '-LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib' '-LC:\opencv\build\include\opencv2' 'FileStorage.cpp'
```

**Error for both:**
*Error using mex
FileStorage.cpp
C:\Dev Matlab\MxArray.hpp(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp': No such file or directory*

Comment: "OpenCV 4.5.5 is installed" -- how, exactly ? the 1st version assumes, you built from src. also, `-LC:\opencv\sources\include` is completely wrong, the folder does not contain, what you need, and `-L` is for library path, not includes.

Comment: also, please clarify, which c++ compiler you try to use.

Comment: @berak C:\opencv\build\include. OpenCV is installed at c:\opencv. Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2019. Mr. Master, can you help so I can be "completely correct" instead of "completely wrong" ?